# Angular Flex Layout - fxLayoutGap.lt-lg="0px grid" - Not working in Safari

Tags: angular, safari, angular-flex-layout

```
    <div class="container" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column"
            fxLayoutGap="48px grid" fxLayoutGap.lt-lg="0px grid">

     <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex fxFlex.lt-lg="100%">
       //Some columns
     </div>

     <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex fxFlex.lt-lg="100%">
      //Some columns
    </div>

    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex fxFlex.lt-lg="100%">
     //Some columns
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the flex layout structure of my code..I have 3 columns which comes one after another without gap in Chrome when the screen size is less than large.

But in Safari, it shows 48px gap between those columns.

How do I fix this?